# How to integrate a bookshelf into a social network application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, social-networking

I have decided that I want to basically create an application (in RoR) that would be built off one of the premade social network frameworks such as Insoshi or Lovdbyless (unless someone can give me other suggestions).

So i want this application to have all the social network features but I would like to add a key functionality for it...The ability for people to add books to the database and then browse through the database and see other books that have been put there by other people and add them to their own personal bookshelf.

I am looking for some direction on how I would go about implementing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. Explore the existing models, views and controllers.
2. Plan your user interface, and undertand how the users will interact with your
   service. Decide in what views will you change or create from new.
3. Plan your data structures. Create the models, migrations,
   validations, associations etc. Think about user access limitations.
4. Plan and create your RESTful resources
5. Create your views and controllers